# Custom path url /v1/myApp/ Google Endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Now, my url is:

> http://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/api/myApp/v1/

And I declared the Api as :

```
@Api(
        name = "myApp",
        version="v1"

        )

public class myAPI {


...

}
```

There is some way to flip the api name and the version in the path or hide version.
something like this:

> http://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/api/v1/myApp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, if you make all of your `@ApiMethod` annotations have paths that start with `/v1/myApp` or `/myApp` (note the leading slash), it will work. I wouldn't recommend it, though.